# ZF2 Console routing doesn't run well

Tags: php, zend-framework

I used Zend Framework version 2. I follow the instruction from [here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.console.controllers.html) but my project doesn't run well. 
Here's my code :

**module.config.php**

```
return array(
    'controllers'=> array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),

    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(

        )
    ),

    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                'list-users' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => 'show [all|disabled|deleted]:mode users [--verbose|-v]',
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                            'action'     => 'showusers'
                        )
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

**Module.php**

```
public function getConsoleUsage(Console $console)
    {
        return array(
            'Finding and listing users',
            'list [all|disabled] users [-w]'    => 'Show a list of users',
            'find user [--email=] [--name=]'    => 'Attempt to find a user by email or name',

            array('[all|disabled]',    'Display all users or only disabled accounts'),
            array('--email=EMAIL',     'Email of the user to find'),
            array('--name=NAME',       'Full name of the user to find.'),
            array('-w',                'Wide output - When listing users use the whole available screen width' ),

            'Manipulation of user database:',
            'delete user <userEmail> [--verbose|-v] [--quick]'  => 'Delete user with email <userEmail>',
            'disable user <userEmail> [--verbose|-v]'           => 'Disable user with email <userEmail>',

            array( '<userEmail>' , 'user email'        , 'Full email address of the user to change.' ),
            array( '--verbose'   , 'verbose mode'      , 'Display additional information during processing' ),
            array( '--quick'     , '"quick" operation' , 'Do not check integrity, just make changes and finish' ),
            array( '-v'          , 'Same as --verbose' , 'Display additional information during processing' ),

        );
    }
```

**IndexController.php**

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function showusersAction(){
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        return "HOLLLLLLLLLLLLAAAAAAAAAAAA"; // show it in the console
    }
}
```

When i tried to run it using command promt :

```
C:\webserver\www\program\phpcas\zf2-console>php public/index.php show users
```

Always showing `getConsoleUsage()` from Module.php, can anyone help me, how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my (little) experience, it seems that your `module.config.php` and your `Module.php` files are correct.

Usually, when I use the console, my controllers are slightly different :

```php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

// For Cron/Console
use Zend\Console\Request as ConsoleRequest;
use Zend\Console\ColorInterface as Color;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function showusersAction()
    {
        // Initialize variables.
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $console = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('console');

        // Make sure that we are running in a console and the user has not tricked our
        // application into running this action from a public web server.
        if (!$request instanceof ConsoleRequest) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('You can only use this action from a console!');
        }

        // Retrieve values from value flags using their name.
        $verbose = (bool)$request->getParam('verbose', false) || (bool)$request->getParam('v', false); // default false
        /* ...your other flags... */

        /* ...do what you want to do... */
        // Let's confirm it works
        $console->writeline("Groovy Baby!");
```